# Oracle SQL query to get max value of records excluding records that have values in both ranges (smaller than max value and bigger than max value)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following situation:

[image]

More details: I want a query that returns the id of the employees that worked until the 6th month (so please read the column month the following way: 1st month, 2nd month, etc.), BUT not those who didn't work after the sixth month.
In my case employee id 3 - ana worked in the 5th month, and also in the eight month. So I want to exclude her. How do I do that? I tried with inner join and group by, but a second condition is missing.

Comment: Anna worked in 8th month , but anna never worked in 3rd month instead she worked in 5th month.According to your table

Comment: that's correct. sorry

Comment: was that a typo - error or something else. So now tell us how you need your query

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking in the question as it is currently written. Please edit it to provide sample Oracle SQL code including (1) a minimum working example (MWE) and (2) your proposed SQL query solution.

Comment: ... I am re-reading the question, and I am not sure I got it. The title seems to suggest you want to find employee id = 3, that is the only employee that has worked both **in** the range and also **outside** the range. But then in the post itself you do something very different. What if there was an employee who worked ONLY outside the range - would you exclude them too?

Comment: @mathguy I agree,  I think the title of question is not aligned with actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need some sort of aggregation query here, because you need to check the work pattern for each worker across all its records.  One option is to `GROUP BY` the `id` and then check that no month greater than 6 occurs.  If you want the full records as your expected output implies, then join to a subquery containing this logic to filter off non matching records.

```
SELECT
    wm1.id,
    wm1.month
FROM worked_months wm1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        id
    FROM worked_months
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN month > 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) wm2
    ON wm1.id = wm2.id
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you could use a conditional analytic SUM to avoid the inner join, fwiw; I think that'd be more performant if you're wanting to see all rows for an id that didn't have any rows past the 6th month

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - LOL, what is the rush with the "correct" or "upvote"? Is there a deadline to achieving a certain rep?

Comment: @Boneist I don't see any way around a subquery here if we want the full record from the `worked_months` table.  If you have such a query in mind then maybe you should post an answer.

Comment: @mathguy No deadline, just noticed a while back that many questions completely ignore answers from a voting point of view.

Comment: You'd still need the subquery, but an analytic function would negate for the join back to the same table.

Comment: @boniest - what is wrong with an anti-join? I see no need for aggregation of any kind (whether using an aggregate or an analytic function).

Comment: @mathguy I didn't say anything about anti-joins; I was merely suggesting an improvement to this answer. I'd recommend the OP tests both and picks the one that works best for them, but that's just common sense!

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to write this is with an anti-join. Run the various solutions on your actual data and see which works best.

```
select id, month
from   worked_months
where  id not in ( select id
                   from   worked_monhts
                   where  month > 6
                 )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

first in the subquery I found the employee ids that worked after 6th month and then exclude those employees from the result set:

the subquery:

```
select id worked_month w
where month > 6
```

the answer:

```
select id, name from employee 
where id not in 
(
  select id worked_month w
  where month > 6
)
```

Comment: Why do you need a join in the subquery? You don't!

Comment: But then it will become identical to my answer (which was already posted when you posted yours).